# Converting xaringan presentation to beamer

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, xaringan

I wrote a very long complicated presentation in xaringan, so I have the underlying rmarkdown file as well as the compiled html.

For reasons of collaboration (the things we do for co-authors!), I need to switch the presentation to beamer. I know xaringan compiles into markdown as a first step before compiling to html. I was wondering if there was a way to compile the xaringan rmarkdown file to a format I could then convert to beamer using pandoc/knitr/rmarkdown etc? Even halfway solutions that get me most of the way to valid beamer code would save me loads of time.

I tried:

`rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', output_format = "beamer_presentation", output_file = "test-beamer.pdf")`

but it doesn't compile and the intermediate `.tex` is a mess: it doesn't recognize `--` as an incremental slide progression, etc. nor really would I expect it to.

Has anyone tried to commit this particular mistake? Is there a way to, say, convert an rmarkdown document in xaringan syntax into an rmarkdown presentation that could target beamer as an output?

Comment: why not just change from `output: xaringan::moon_reader` to `output: beamer_presentation` in the rmarkdown file?

Comment: thanks @alanocallaghan for the thought. that gets me the same lack of compilation + disfunctional tex file as the strategy i mentioned of calling `rmarkdown::render`. In fact its the same thing I believe

Comment: I've never had issues switching between the two, and it's difficult to debug further without knowing what the source or the specific issues are